# Traceback objects in python

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I was debugging my python script and came across `traceback` object, which is present at 2nd index in result, returned by `sys.exc_info()` function. However, I tried to google out information related to `traceback` object, but everywhere i got link to `traceback module` in standard python lib. Then, I tried doing `dir()` on traceback object, which gives me a list of attributes. In that list, following attributes looks interesting :-

```
 1. tb_frame,
 2. tb_lasti,
 3. tb_lineno,
 4. tb_next
```

I know about tb_frame and tb_lineno, but what rest of other attributes indicates ?

Apologizing for bad English. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=tb_

Comment: Also [this](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=tb_) page

Comment: How do you turn that into something human-readable?

Answer (score 4):

As specified by in docpage specified by @vaultah,

These all are special read-only attributes.

1. `tb_next` is the next level in the stack trace (towards the frame where the exception occurred), or None if there is no next level;
2. `tb_frame` points to the execution frame of the current level;
3. `tb_lineno` gives the line number where the exception occurred;
4. `tb_lasti` indicates the precise instruction.

**Note :-**
The line number and last instruction in the traceback may differ from the line number of its frame object if the exception occurred in a try statement with no matching except clause or with a finally clause.